# Can I prevent Nuget from installing my package's dependency into a destination project?

Tags: nuget, razorgenerator

I'm creating a nuget package for my open source project and I've run into an issue that I'd like someone to help me with.

My project is depending on a package called [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator). This is a great package that allows me to compile my Razor views (.cshtml) into my dll.

To enable this functionality, the RazorGenerator.Mvc package seems to consist of a powershell script that adds a file `RazorGeneratorMvcStart.cs` to my project's `App_Start` directory. This is fine.

However, since my project is depending on this package, whenever someone installs my nuget package, the same powershell script seems to be run in their project. This is because the `RazorGenerator.Mvc` package is installed into the user's project alongside my nuget package.

Is there a way to prevent this? I would prefer if this script only runs in my local project to embed my Razor views into my resulting .dll, and not to run in my user's projects.

In other words, my project needs to remain dependent on `RazorGenerator.Mvc`, but I would like to prevent destination projects to be dependent on it as well (they are already depending on my package). The `RazorGenerator.Mvc` package has done its job in compiling the Razor views and does not need to be installed into my users' projects.

Hope this made sense. Thanks for any response!

Comment: This is not possible if the project it is being installed into uses packages.config file. The only way for this to work would be for you to just include RazorGenerator.Mvc assemblies in your NuGet package. Other project formats, such as that used by .NET Core, do not support PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Do you use a nuspec to pack the file? it has options to controls which assets are consumed by the referencing projects - the same as `PrivateAssets` on a `PackageReference`